# Why am I getting an empty output when I print the content of GET respose using requests module of python?

Tags: python, get, python-requests

I am using

> python requests

to perform POST and GET requests on a particular API.
I am trying to do this:

```
print get_response.content
```

But I am getting an empty output. I tried hitting the same GET request using CURL command. That prints the content of the get response in detail. I also used :

```
print get_response.text
```

For this also I am getting no output printed. What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to check `r.status_code` its looks like your request from python fails

Comment: Well the status code is 200. But the content is not getting printed out

Comment: ok good, but i can help more if you put in your question some additional info, code where you send request from python and your curl command with  output

Comment: import requests
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()
from requests.auth import HTTPDigestAuth

url = myURL
credId = 'user'
credPwd = 'test'

r = requests.get(url , auth = HTTPDigestAuth(credId, credPwd), verify =False)
print r
print r.content
print r.status_code

Comment: And the URL, username and password are confidential. Hence I have arbitrarily given them so as to give the entire skeleton of my script

Answer (score 0):

I think, from your example, that you are jumping the gun, you need to do the `get` first.

```
>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.get('https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests')
>>> r.status_code
200
>>> r.content
```

Edit, subsequent to your comment:
Have you tried printing out

```
r.headers
r.headers['content-length']
r.headers['server']
```

etc
That may give you a clue as to what is going on.

Comment: In fact I am performing the get request with all that is needed to get through the login page using DigestAuth of python. Still facing the issue and that is why am bemused of what to do

Comment: In that case you are going to have to provide your code, so that we have something to work with

Comment: import requests
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()
from requests.auth import HTTPDigestAuth

url = "https://tenant1alcatrazactiancecomrugsei/cxf/alcatraz/participants/profiles"
credId = 'whiteboxtester'
credPwd = 'test123'

r = requests.get(url , auth = HTTPDigestAuth(credId, credPwd), verify =False)
print r
print r.content
print r.status_code